Explanation for a small step in the proof of Minkowski's inequality, Theorem 3.5, Rudin's RCA
I have a minor issue with understanding Rudin's proof of Minkowski's inequality.

Here is the section of the proof regarding Minkwoski's inequality:

I'm having trouble understanding the case that the righthand side of $(10)$ is $\infty$. I see that if
$$
\big\{\int_X f^p\ d\mu \big\}^{\frac{1}{p}}  + \big\{\int_X g^p\ d\mu \big\}^{\frac{1}{p}}\big\} = \infty
$$
then the desired inequality obviously holds. But what about $\big\{\int_X (f+g)^p\ d\mu \big\}^{\frac{1}{q}}$? Does the convexity of $t^p$ implies this expression must be finite aswell? Or is there another arugment to be made that implies that the inequality holds when $\big\{\int_X (f+g)^p\ d\mu \big\}^{\frac{1}{q}}$ is infinite?

If $
\big{\int_X f^p\ d\mu \big}^{\frac{1}{p}}  + \big{\int_X g^p\ d\mu \big}^{\frac{1}{p}}\big} <\infty
$ then $\int f^{p} <\infty$  and $\int g^{p} <\infty$ so $\int (f+g)^{p} <\infty$ because $((f+g)/2)^{p} \le (f^{p}+g^{p}) /2$.

@geetha290krm My professor used Jensen's inequality to say that since $t^p$ is convex $\big{\int_X (f+g)^p\ d\mu \big}^{\frac{1}{q}}$ is finite, but I don't see why we need to use Jensen's inequality here. Is it really necessary?

No, just definition of convexity of $t^{p}$ is enough.
